# what is the difference between iter++->empty() and ++iter->empty()?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Assuming that iter is a `vector<string>::iterator`.

1. I have understood that `++iter->empty()` is illegal, ISO C++17 does not allow incrementing expression of type bool, indicating that `++iter->empty()` equals `++(iter->empty())`.
2. Based on (1), why `iter++->empty()` doesn't equal `(iter->empty())++` or `((*iter).empty())++`, but equals `(*iter++).empty()`?
   thank you very much!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Those are simply the operator precedence rules, making the rules different when it's more convenient would be super complex and confusing

Comment: Post increment `++` always comes after the thing it's incrementing. In `iter++->empty()`, it very obviously comes after `iter` but before `empty()`.

Comment: but ++ has a lower precedence than ->, how to understand the order in which operators will be evaluated in the situation where they co-occur one by one? thank you very much

Comment: what's more, form  the statement that "Post increment ++ always comes after the thing it's incrementing.", the statement that prefix increment ++ always comes before the thing it's incrementing should be correct, so ++iter->empty() should equal iter->empty(), ++iter, not equal ++(iter->empty()); but it doesn't.

Comment: @XMan In general `++iter->foo()` would be ambiguous without the operator precedence rules, it could reasonably interpreted as either `(++iter)->foo()` or `++(iter->foo())` (if `foo()` returned a reference to e.g. an int, this would be legal). `iter++->foo()` is not ambiguous, since `++->foo()` would never be legal, the only way to parse it is as `(iter++)->foo()`. Your alternative interpretation of `iter->foo()++` requires us to move the operator somewhere else in the expression entirely.

Comment: Operators with higher precedence are evaluated first. This is what operator precedence is for. Like in 2+3*4, the * is evaluated first. Also, x++ and ++x are completely different operators. They even have different precedence.

Comment: In `iter++->empty()` there are three postfix operators in a row: `++` then `->empty` then `()`. They are executed *left to right* , each subsequent one being applied to the result of the previous one.

Comment: @Kyle so you mean that, when we try to interpret an expression, we should not move any operator?

Comment: @all , I have an idea that there may be a trick in the interpretation of iter++->empty(). the reason why iter++->empty() equals (iter++)->empty() is  that iter->empty(), iter = iter+1 (post ++ has a lower precedence than ->) equals (iter++)->empty().  So how does a compiler interpret the expression iter++->empty()?

Comment: @XMan Operator precedence is not a constraint on order of evaluation, precedence is only used to resolve ambiguous expressions. There is no ambiguity with `iter++->foo()`, so there's no reason to invoke precedence rules.